# How to publish my Windows Phone 8.0 app in the Windows Phone Store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I have developed a Windows Phone 8.0 App.

How do I deploy or publish it to the Windows Phone Store?

Are there any step by step instructions on how to do it?

I would like to publish my .xap file in the Windows Phone Store or Windows Store so that users can download it for free.

Comment: Have you read the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206736(v=vs.105).aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this information can be found on the Windows Phone Dev Center.

Here is information on creating your App Info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206733(v=vs.105).aspx

And here are details on uploading your XAP package: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206723(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just take a look [here](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us) at the Dev Center of Microsoft for the Windows Phone. There you will need to create an acoount to publish your Apps. You will find a link called `Submit App` or `Publish` at the top. Just follow the steps mentioned there.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you have to create a developer account. 
[link to create account](http://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us). There you can publish your app. After submitting your app, Microsoft will review it. If pass the review it will available for public, else you have to make changes as they say and have to resubmit it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to fulfill these requirements before you submit your app to app store.
[App submission requirements for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184844%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)